# SimpleXML match element on hyphenated attribute value

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am trying to get the value of a 'sibling' attribute by finding the node that has an attribute with a certain value. However the node and the attributes are all hyphenated.

Example: I want to get the value of the attribute 'code-key'. This is where I am so far.

```
$code_key_value = $xml->{'hyphenated-node'}['hyphenated-attribute="a value"']['code-key'];
```

`hyphenated-attribute` and `code-key` are both attributes of `hyphenated-node`

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with the hyphen in the attribute name, you can't find a node by an attribute value that way anyway. Maybe you should look into XPath.

Comment: So how would you suggest I find a node by an attribute value if I can't do it that way anyway?

Comment: Like I say, XPath allows you to do something very similar to what you tried. Or you just loop over the possibilities with a foreach and test the attribute values with a normal if statement.